# GCC returns error - 'implicit declaration of function 'truncate''

Tags: c, gcc

in my school project we are making a copy program with a couple of flags. I need to truncate an infile after copying. 
This is the code for it:

```
int a_trunc(const char* infile, const char* size){
    int s = strtol(size, NULL, 10);
    truncate(infile, s);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC returns error: 'implicit declaration of function 'truncate''.

I have sys/types.h and unistd.h included.

I am compiling with flags:
    -std=c99 -Wall -Werror

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with flag -std=gnu99 ?

Comment: Also try with -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE

Comment: The GCC compiler running in "GNU mode" `-std=gnu90` (which is the default setting up to GCC version 5) dumps all manner of non-standard junk in standard libraries. This isn't allowed by the C standard, so when you tell it to compile the code as standard C, it removes the non-standard junk. Possibly, it removes a bit too much in this case. POSIX tends to collide with standard C here and there, might be why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that because `truncate()` is not declared with a prototype before you try to use it.

Per [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <unistd.h>
>    #include <sys/types.h>
>
>    int truncate(const char *path, off_t length);
>    int ftruncate(int fd, off_t length);
> ```

While you need to `#include` both `unistd.h` and `sys/types.h`, it's not sufficient.  GCC/Linux also requires specific feature macro definitions:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    truncate():
>        _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
>            || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
>            || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
>
>    ftruncate():
>        _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
>            || /* Since glibc 2.3.5: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
>            || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
> ```

Using `-std=c99` would be one way to get those.

Comment: As I said I have both of those included. And why do I have to declare a prototype if I have both .h files included? Every other function in that program works. Only truncate is getting this error.

Comment: Well It worked but I have no idea why... THanks a lot anyway

Comment: @Erik Post all of your code and maybe it'd be possible to know why.

Comment: @Erik The solution is not to write the prototypes yourself, that should never be necessary. You should probably just switch to `-std=gnu99` when using those libraries. Apparently something inside them collides with standard C.

Comment: I'm slow today...